# Compare and Output 2 strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to make a web page where if I have the same open and closing hours for 5 days a week, it will output them on the same line. For example, the hours for Monday - Friday are the same in my example so it would print out:

Monday - Friday: 6:00AM - 2:00PM
Saturday 8:00AM - 1:00PM 
Sunday Closed (Without the hyphen)

When I run this in my browser, I get a blank page. Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
      <head>
      <script>


    var MondayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var MondayClose = "2:00PM";
    var TuesdayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var TuesdayClose = "2:00PM";
    var WednesdayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var WednesdayClose = "2:00PM";
    var ThursdayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var ThursdayClose = "2:00PM";
    var FridayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var FridayClose = "2:00PM";
    var SaturdayOpen =  "8:00AM - ";
    var SaturdayClose = "1:00PM";
    var SundayOpen =  "Closed";
    var SundayClose = "";

var dateArray = new Array(MondayOpen, MondayClose, TuesdayOpen, TuesdayClose, WednesdayOpen, WednesdayClose, ThursdayOpen, ThursdayClose,FridayOpen, FridayClose, SaturdayOpen, SaturdayClose, SundayOpen, SundayClose);

  function outputDate(){

    for(int i = 0; i<dateArray.length; i++){
    var current;

    //Puts Open and Close time into 1 string
    dateArray[i] + dateArray[i+1] = current;

      //Compare the two strings
      if(current.substring(0,15) == current.substring(0,15) +2)
    }

           $("#hours").html(<b> current <b/>);
    }
 var getHours = document.getElementById('hours').innterHTML = current;
    }

</script>   

  <div id= "hours" style="font-size:10px; color:#fff;"> 


  </div>
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `String` supposed to be? Did you mean to do `var` instead?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I will edit this here now. I still get a blank page though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a step back and master JavaScript and HTML. There are many free resources available. Just to be brief, why not try [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/) or [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/). That being said, here's enough of a fix to display your variables.

```
  <html>

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

      <title></title>

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="hours"></div>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var MondayOpen =  "6:00AM - "; 
    var MondayClose = "2:00PM";
    var TuesdayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var TuesdayClose = "2:00PM";
    var WednesdayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var WednesdayClose = "2:00PM";
    var ThursdayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var ThursdayClose = "2:00PM";
    var FridayOpen =  "6:00AM - ";
    var FridayClose = "2:00PM";
    var SaturdayOpen =  "8:00AM - ";
    var SaturdayClose = "1:00PM";
    var SundayOpen =  "Closed";
    var SundayClose = "";

    var dateArray = new Array(MondayOpen, MondayClose, TuesdayOpen, TuesdayClose, WednesdayOpen, WednesdayClose, ThursdayOpen, ThursdayClose,FridayOpen, FridayClose, SaturdayOpen, SaturdayClose, SundayOpen, SundayClose);

    function outputDate(){
      var printOutResults;
      for(i = 0; i<dateArray.length; i++) {
        var current;
        //Puts Open and Close time into 1 string
        current = dateArray[i] + dateArray[i+1]; 
        printOutResults += current;
        //Compare the two 
        if(current.substring(0,15) == current.substring(0,15) +2){
           $("#hours").html(current);
        }
       }
         $("#hours").html(printOutResults);
    }

    outputDate(); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes here. Just to name a few:

You put `int` instead of `var` here:

```
for(var i = 0; i<dateArray.length; i++){
```

You put `String` instead of `var` here:

```
var curr;
```

You're assigning a variable to an expression? Did you mean to do it the other way around?

```
//Puts Open and Close time into 1 string
curr = dateArray[i] + dateArray[i+1];
```

You have a closing brace after your `if` statement...

```
  //Compare the two strings
  if(current.substring(0,15) == current.substring(0,15) +2)
{
```

You type `innterHTML` instead of `innerHTML` and try to do multiple assignments:

```
 var getHours = current;
 document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = current;
```

You forget to enclose this in quotes:

```
 $("#hours").html("<b> current <b/>");
```

EVEN after fixing all these syntax errors I get a blank page. Consider rewriting it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you don't need to declare String theString = "This is a string".
Just write var stringName = "This is my string."